# Вызов функций из словаря

Tags: python

Приветствую,

имеется некий словарь заменяющий конструкцию `switch..case` :

```
def __insert_value_with_the_key(self, key, value):
        switcher = {
            'AAA': self.__call_func1(value),
            'BBB': self.__call_func2(value),
            'CCC': self.__call_func3(value),
        }
        switcher.get(key)
```

А помимо словаря эти 3 фунции:

```
def __call_func1(self, value)
    self.aaa_hashmap[value] = True

def __call_func2(self, value)
    self.bbb_hashmap[value] = True

def __call_func3(self, value)
    self.ccc_hashmap[value] = True
```

**Хочу избавиться от этих функций**, а увы сделать что-то такое :

```
'AAA' : lambda : self.aaa_hashmap[value] = True
```

НЕЛЬЗЯ! Пользоваться `if` я не хочу (ибо функций куда уж больше 3, а изменяется только одно значение в словаре (ex. `self.aaa_hashmap`))

Что можете посоветовать?

Comment: у вас все три функции всегда вызываются. switch..case совсем не так работает (только один вариант должен срабатывать). Какая у вас задача изначальная была? Вы хотите аналог [ChainMap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) реализовать?

Comment: спасибо за беспокойство, но уже правильный ответ я отметил)

Comment: от этого код в вопросе более правильным не становится. Вопросы на Stack Overflow не только лично для вас, но и для будущих читателей из поисковика.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.aaa_hashmap = {}
        self.bbb_hashmap = {}
        self.ccc_hashmap = {}

    self.switcher = {
        'AAA': lambda value: dict.__setitem__(self.aaa_hashmap, value, True),
        'BBB': lambda value: dict.__setitem__(self.bbb_hashmap, value, True),
        'CCC': lambda value: dict.__setitem__(self.ccc_hashmap, value, True),
    }

def __insert_value_with_the_key(self, key, value):
    self.switcher.get(key)(value)
```

или

```
def __init__(self):
    self.aaa_hashmap = {}
    self.bbb_hashmap = {}
    self.ccc_hashmap = {}
    self.switcher = {'AAA': self.aaa_hashmap, 'BBB': self.bbb_hashmap, 'CCC': self.ccc_hashmap}
    self.insert_value_with_the_key = lambda key, value: dict.__setitem__(self.switcher[key], value, True)
```

Comment: нет необходимости здесь использовать синтаксис: `klass.method(obj, *args)`. Лучше `obj.method(*args)`. К примеру: `self.some_dict.__setitem__(key, value)`

Answer (score 3):

```
getattr(self, lower(key) + '_hashmap')[value] = True
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но чуть-чуть не то -  хочу от функций вообще избавиться

Comment: Так в ответе нет ни одной функции, кроме встроенных.

Comment: Извиняюсь, неправильно понял. Но названия хэштаблиц могут не иметь связи в названиях или чем-то незначительным отличаться

Comment: @koshachok тогда просто `lower(key)`  на `key2hash[key]` замените, чтобы имена hashmap независимо от значений key менять.